# Вызов функции при изменении значения select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```
<select onchange="chcost('10','20');">
    <option value="0">Количество показов</option>
    <option value="1">1.000</option>
    <option value="2">2.000</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function chcost(id, prise) {
    alert('ok');
};
```

Итог:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: chcost is not defined

Обёртывание в `$(function() { });` не помогает.

Comment: Код прекрасно работает в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6v6bcqe/). А вот оборачивать функцию в `document.ready` действительно не стоит.

Comment: Может у вас объявление функции располагается ниже, чем её вызов?

Comment: @OmBird местоположение скрипта с функцией (в `<head>` или в конце `<body>`)  не имеет значения. Всё равно функция будет вызываться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотря как вы подключаете свой скрипт. Если он у вас находится во внешнем файле, то вы не можете гарантировать, что скрипт у вас загрузится до того момента как начнётся построение DOM'а. В этом случае на этапе, когда привязывается обработчик события `onchange`, функция еще не существует следовательно ссылка на неё не создастся и при попытке вызова вы получите: `Uncaught ReferenceError: chcost is not defined`.

Если вы хотите вызывать функцию именно этим способом (привязывать обработчики из DOM, что **крайне не рекомендуется в данном случае**), то вам следует "внедрить её в DOM". Когда браузер читает HTML-страничку, и видит `<script>` - он первым делом читает и выполняет код, а только потом продолжает читать страницу дальше.

Соответственно в вашем случае код будет выглядеть так:

```
<script>
function chcost(id, prise) {
    alert('ok');
};    
</script>
<select onchange="chcost('10','20');">
    <option value="0">Количество показов</option>
    <option value="1">1.000</option>
    <option value="2">2.000</option>
</select>
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/b2bn0r7o/

Вот более полезный пример (с использованием jQuery):
http://jsfiddle.net/csLAk/6492/

Здесь мы гарантируем что скрипт загрузился и DOM уже построен. И привязываем к **существующему** select'у функцию(обработчик).

PS: В глубокой теории не силён, потому возможны некоторые неточности в объяснении)